# How to average array per 100 chunks

Tags: php, arrays

I'm wondering how to split an array into 100 chunks and then average the values in those chunks. I came as far as using array_chunk but can't figure out how to average the value in those chunks. This is a small part of my array:

```
Array ( [0] => 70 [1] => 70 [2] => 70 [3] => 69 [4] => 69 [5] => 69 [6] => 70 [7] => 70 [8] => 70 [9] => 69 [10] => 69 [11] => 70 [12] => 70 [13] => 69 [14] => 70 [15] => 69 [16] => 69 [17] => 70 [18] => 69 [19] => 69 [20] => 69 [21] => 69 [22] => 69  ...
```

What I want is the following:

[0] = > 70 (Average of the first 100 values in the array)

And so on

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try the `array_chunk()` function. Here is the link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: Could you break up that long line of code for us? :)

Comment: Use `array_sum()` on your chunk and divide by the `count()` in the array. Presto! Average.

Comment: Thanks Jared for the solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = array_chunk(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), 3);

while ($chunk = array_shift($arr)) {
    echo array_sum($chunk) / count($chunk) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

http://codepad.org/uaY1ziEI

Gives:

```
2
5
8
```

And if you change it to `4` per chunk:

```
2.5
6.5
9
```

http://codepad.org/srGW4Rmq

EDIT: 100 chunks:

```
$arr = range(1, 16734, 1);
$arr = array_chunk($arr, ceil(count($arr) / 100));

while ($chunk = array_shift($arr)) {
    echo array_sum($chunk) / count($chunk) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

http://codepad.org/t1n9VE35

Comment: great solution, but I know the chunks (100) what I don't know is how many values there are per chunk

Comment: I'm not sure, is that a question?

Comment: Yes, your method cuts the array in chunks of 3 but I need to work the other way around. I need 100 chunks actually

Comment: @BartScheffer - See the edit. Your question doesn't make that clear at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = range(1, 200);

$arrs = array_chunk($arr, 5); // 5 is a number of elements in chunk
foreach($arrs as $chunk)
  echo array_sum($chunk) / count($chunk) . "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the average for the first 100, something like this will do:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, 100);
$sum = round(array_sum($chunks[0]) / count($a), 2);

echo $sum;
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/206058)