# Cluster large dataset into groups of 500/700

Tags: php, highcharts

**Hi everyone!** I'm working with a large tab delimited file which contains counts and lengths. I want to display this large data set in a `HighCharts`, but the count can go up to 100k. Trying to display this will be a lost cause.. so I want to cluster the data in sets of 500/700! An example of my data:

```
35  1265
36  1310
37  1180
38  1064
39  938
40  906
41  821
42  903
43  845
44  816
45  815
46  853
47  858
.......
72721   1
72732   1
72878   1
72984   1
73138   1
73279   1
73283   1
73379   1
74322   1
74373   1
75038   1
76222   1
76606   1
77153   1
78573   1
80839   1
```

I have tried to find an example of a bar/column chart in `HighCharts` that can work with this, but no luck yet. It is a part of a `Laravel` website, so my best option (I thought) is altering the data in `PHP` before using it in `HighCharts`.

I want to have a loop that fills an array with the sum of all the second values between count 0 and 500, and then another array filled with the sum of all the data from 501-1000.. I have tried searching on the internet, but I must be google'ing wrong. Does someone have any suggestions on how I could handle this?
I want the output to look something like this:

```
0-500       23520
501-1000    235216
1001-1500   235138
```

Comment: Go through the values in a loop. Divide the first number by 500, and use floor of the result to round it down to the nearest integer. Use that as the key for a new array, and sum up the second numbers in the value.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372330/how-to-average-array-per-100-chunks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to average array per 100 chunks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372330/how-to-average-array-per-100-chunks)